# How do I create a reversi function that encloses opponents tiles?

Tags: python

I have an assignment for a programming unit that asks this:

create the function enclosing(board, player, pos, direct), that represents the rules of Reversi according to the following specifications.

A board position is represented by a pair (r, c) where r and c are each integers from the range
range(8) representing a row index and a column index, respectively. For instance, the position \b3" is
represented by (2, 1). The row and column order of the \b3" style and the specication of position
is reversed. This is because it is natural to constuct lists of lists in such a way that the outer lists
correspond to rows, and the inner list positions corerspond to column positions, so we reference them
with row rst, then column. This row, column convention is quite common across maths and computer
science.

A direction is represented by a pair (dr, dc) where dr and dc are each integers from the set f-1, 0,
1g. For instance, \horizontal to the left" is described by (0, -1), \diagonal to the right and down" is
described by (1, 1), and so on).

The function enclosing(board, player, pos, dir) represents whether putting a player's stone on
a given position would enclose a straight line of opponent's stones in a given direction:

Input: A board conguration board, an integer player from the set f1, 2g, a board position pos and a direction dir.

Output: True if board contains a stone of player in direction dir from position pos and all positions
on the straight line between that stone and pos contain stones of the other player, and there is at
least one stone belonging to the other player on the straight line; False otherwise.

This is what I have:

```
def enclosing(board, player, pos, direct):
    if player == 1:
        a = direct[0]
        b = direct[1]
        i = 1
        while i < 8:
            newpos = (pos[0] + i*a , pos[1] + i*b)
            if board[newpos[0]][newpos[1]] == 1:
                return True
            elif board[newpos[0]][newpos[1]] == 2:    
                i = i + 1
            else:
                return False
```

Also keep in mind this is a beginners course and I have about a months experience on python.

Comment: Your conceptual start is mostly right, but you're over-complicating it. According to the instructions, you don't need to iterate through all the current positions. The starting position is given as `pos`.

Comment: This is the example of how the code should work: "Calling enclosing(new board(), 1, (4, 5), (0, -1)) returns True because Player 1 canenclose one opponent's stone to the left when placing a stone on eld \f5". In contrast, there is no straight line of opponent's stones to enclose on the diagonal line to the bottom right. Therefore, enclosing(new board(), 1, (4, 5), (1, 1)) returns False."
from this i thought that position is where a person would like to place a tile and that therefore youd have to iterate through all the currentpositions and test the direction tosee if any could reach position

Comment: What I wrote is still true. Think about how you would implement that function if the board were drawn on a grid, and you could only look at one cell at a time. Which cells in the board would you look at?

Comment: ??? I barely understand the question let alone how I would do that *cri*

Comment: :( Do you know how to play reversi/othello? Playing the game online would probably make it way easier to understand the rules

Comment: Yes I do, but I'm really inexperienced with python and uni tends to throw you in the deep end with things

Comment: Yeah, it can be rough.... For the function you have to write, the input is the move, and the output is whether you flip any of your opponent's tiles. How would you explain to someone who doesn't know how to play which tiles to flip?

Comment: I'm not sure, i think I could piece together the code however I dont know where/how I would implement direction.

Comment: How about: start where you place the new tile. Then choose a direction from `{left right up down diagonal*4}` and move one cell at a time in that direction. See if you make any of these patterns: `XOX, XOOX, XOOOX`, where `X` are your tiles and `O` are your opponents' tiles. Hope that's useful as a starting point

Comment: I think that helps actually. Thank you!!

Comment: I updated my code do you think this will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your edit looks good, and is what I was getting at. Good luck with the rest of the project!

A couple edge cases:

1. `board[newpos[0]][newpos[1]]` will go out of bounds
2. Your function will return True in the case `XOOOOX`, which is not a capture by Othello rules (not sure if your assignment defines it differently

I strongly recommend writing a couple simple tests just to make sure your code works. They don't need to cover the full range of cases, and doesn't need to be the full board. It's usually not required, but makes it easier to evaluate: just hit "run" instead of trying to reason through your code.

Here's an example:

```
def test():
    assert enclosing([[0, 0, 0], [0,0,0],[0,1,2]], 1, (0,2), (1,1)) == True
```